# If a business plan is implemented does it become prior art?

Tags: prior-art, business-methods

Does a business-method become prior art once it is implemented?. Is there a grace period of 1 year from implementation to filing the patent?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, a business method, product, or process, becomes "prior art" once it is publicly disclosed, used, or sold.
2. Yes, the US provides a one year grace period from the time of initial disclosure, sale, or public use to file a patent application.  However, the US is now a first-to-file country, so it's not a good idea to wait.